# how to add a clickHandler on a subRow of celltable in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using Custom Data Grid from GWT showcase example ..
http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCustomDataGrid

Every thing is working fine ..I have sub Rows inside my rows in the cell table ..

I have anchor cell.. which are in the main row and in the sub row ..

the `ClickHandler` for the main row is working but not in the sub row ..

this is my code for that cell

```
// ViewDetail.
td = row.startTD();
td.className(cellStyles);
td.style().trustedColor("blue");
td.style().cursor(Cursor.POINTER);

if (isNetworkRow) {
  //td.text("subRowsAnchor");
} else {

}
renderCell(td, createContext(19), viewDetailsColumn, rowValue);
```

I am rendering the cell in both cases , either its a row or sub row
so i can see the anchor and its clickHandler also works ..

Is there any way i can differentiate that which anchor is been clicked ,, main rows or sub row's.

I just tried to make a small work around . i.e changing the name of the anchor text if its a sub row .. as u can c in my code  ..`td.text`..

but then get the error on renderCell...

> Attributes cannot be added after appending HTML or adding a child element.

Any idea , what could be solution...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish between which row has been clicked (according to the showcase sample, but should be the same in general), simply rely on which row has been *selected* (provided that you haven't overridden/disabled the selection handling).

Set up a `FieldUpdater` to the column (that renders itself using your anchor cell) and check for the subrow selection using [`getKeyboardSelectedSubRow()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractCellTable.html#getKeyboardSelectedSubRow%28%29). Something like:

```
yourColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<T, String>() {
  public void update(int index, T object, String value) {
    if (yourGrid.getKeyboardSelectedRow() != -1 ) {
      if (yourGrid.getKeyboardSelectedSubRow() > 0) {
        // Subrow selected.
      } else {
        // Main row selected.
      }
    }
  }
});
```